# Quantile R unused argument error

Tags: r

I want to use the quantile function, the example shown under "help"

```
x <- rnorm(1001)
quantile(x <- rnorm(1001)) # Extremes & Quartiles by default
quantile(x,  probs = c(0.1, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 50, NA)/100)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in quantile(x, probs = c(0.1, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 50, NA)/100) : 
 unused argument (probs = c(0.1, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 50, NA)/100)
```

The argument probs does not seems to work. I tried many other variations. Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks, Felix

Comment: I can't reproduce your error,  it works fine on my end.  Try starting a fresh R session and re-run it.

Comment: and/or try `stats::quantile(...)` to make sure you're getting the right version of the function.